# Android Google Maps application showing grey background instead of the map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

OK, I'm having the weirdest bug right now : the Android application I'm working on is displaying a grey background instead of the map, such as below :

[image: WTF]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/572343Screenshot20130425161918.jpg))</sub>

Here's the logcat :

```
04-25 15:08:42.082: E/Google Maps Android API(19139): Failed to load map.  Could not contact Google servers.
04-25 15:08:42.082: W/Google Maps Android API(19139): Please add <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> into AndroidManifest.xml to ensure correct behavior under poor connectivity conditions.
```

I have NO idea what might have caused this. I only changed a small part of my code that was completely unrelated to the map. And besides, I tried reverting the changes I made, and it still didn't work. I tried adding the line the logcat gave me, changing the API key, re-installing the Google Play library, deleting the previous versions of my app on my tablet, basically pretty much everything that I read on the Internet. Still doesn't work.

If anyone has any idea what the problem might be, that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is caused when there is a problem with your key or a problem with it's configuration in the Google API Console.

Go over this blog post I wrote on how to produce the key and integrate in in the console:

[Google Maps API V2 key](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

if this is not helpful you can try to delete the `dubug.keystore` folder in you user folder, compile
some project in eclipe (which result in regenerating this key) and try to register it again.

**UPDATE:**
From the new error you posted, do you have this permission in your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: I don't think there's a problem with my SHA1 key because I have another project which uses it, and this it works perfectly. I also already tried generating a new key but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: and what about the permission?

Comment: try to register your SHA1 to a new project in the console and set the new API_Key you will receive in your project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: set the `“Custom debug keystore”` setting (`empty by default`) to the same value as the `“Default debug keystore”` in the Eclipse preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Emil's post above helped me, I was getting the same error and realised that this was due to me changing the name of my project. I added the changed name along with the same SHA1 I had for my old project on a new line (leaving the one with the old name above) in the console and it seemed to work as normal.