# Why Google maps stopped working?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-studio

I have done an application for android , and I used Android Studio , in this app I need  to use Google maps, so while I was working i did  all that stuff about the API key  to use google maps,  i was proving my app  on my own movile, and there everything works fine, even  googlemaps,  but when I  put my app on the store, i downloaded it  from another device, and there google maps does not work. =(
Do you have any  idea why does this  happen ?

Comment: Did you add the SHA1 fingerprint of your release keystore to the API key?  It sounds like you may have only added the debug SHA1 key, which would make it only work from your dev environment and not the release APK.

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance, but im new on this , i think you are tight , but i have some problems , when i try  to get my release fingerprint , can you teachme how ? @DanielNugent

Comment: what  I did was to put this command line:   keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\Manuel Rios\Documents\Mi Carpeta\millave.jks"
and then i have an output with a sha1 finger print but how do i know if it is the release fingerptiny

Comment: If that's the keystore that you used to sign your release apk, then that is the one to use.  You can just add the SHA1 fingerprint to your existing API Key in the Developer Console, and that should make it work.  Be sure to uninstall/re-install before testing after updating the API key.

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30462081/android-google-maps-only-a-grey-background-as-apk/30462918#30462918

Comment: should i create a new apk  ?  and put it on the store ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to replace the apk, as long as you add the SHA1 used to sign that apk to your API key.  But again, before testing you will need to uninstall/re-install (as will everyone who initially installed the app) for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

There might be an issue with your API key for map. (ie. Either there is issue in defining package name or SHA key)
Try to re-generate API key with all proper info. and re-build your project.